# Hermes is not working in Android with React-native 0.60.2

Tags: android, react-native

I've upgraded React-native in existing (not new) project to 0.60.2 by way of changing package.json as written here https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.59.10&to=0.60.2

In android/app/build.gradle I put: 
p

```
roject.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: true  // clean and rebuild if changing
]
```

build is successfull, but Hermes does not seems to work, in RN 0.59.0 apk was 29 Mb, now it's 46 Mb.

If I add other changes to build.gradle as here https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.59.10&to=0.60.2

then I get error:
Could not read script '/Users/mac/Desktop/aqua2/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' as it does not exist.

probably because of the last line:

```
apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

how can I solve this?

Comment: Did you update your [`android/app/build.gradle` dependency block](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/60e75dc1ab73b2893ec2e25c0320f32b3cf12b80/template/android/app/build.gradle#L190)?

Comment: @yevgen-pashutin have u found any solution yet? I am facing the same issue with a new project. `global.HermesInternal` seems to be `undefined`

Comment: I'm also getting `undefined` and I follow all the instructions for  `build.graddle`

Answer (score 0):

you should give second parameter to the applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle function. I got from your file direction, your root is upper. That's why i'm saying you should give your root direction as second paramater.

- your node modules direction

  **file**("../../node_modules/
- you should do that

  **applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle**(project, **"../"**)